# Classification using logistic regression - Iris dataset

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am working on a random exercise online on Logistics regression. It is using sample data from Iris dataset. Usually, when we use load_iris() dataset, we use data in X and target in y to predict the model. However, this specific exercise contains only 4 columns (see data below). I tried to use random values for y (manual) and I can predict the model, however, it is failing in validating part where it checks the output length.

No of Input records - 50
Expected Output length - 50

As far I see, we predict the model bases on training set and training set should not be  full data. I am confused whether the question is wrong or I am lacking knowledge here.

Have given the input file and my code below. Appreciate any suggestions on this.

========================================================

Question -

## 1. Predict the labels for the data stored in `test_iris.csv`.

## 2. Store the predictions in the form of list to the variable `list_ans`. Note: List numbers are of integer type.

Input file - test_iris.csv

---

```
sepal length (cm),sepal width (cm),petal length (cm),petal width (cm)
  5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2
  5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4
  5,3.5,1.6,0.6
  7.2,3,5.8,1.6
  7,3.2,4.7,1.4
  6.3,2.7,4.9,1.8
  6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5
  5.5,2.3,4,1.3
  6.3,2.5,5,1.9
  4.9,3,1.4,0.2
  6.5,3,5.2,2
  5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1
  5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4
  7.7,2.8,6.7,2
  6.1,3,4.9,1.8
  6.4,2.9,4.3,1.3
  5.6,3,4.1,1.3
  5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3
  4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2
  6.1,2.6,5.6,1.4
  5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1
  5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2
  5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2
  6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4
  6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3
  5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3
  5,2.3,3.3,1
  5.8,2.8,5.1,2.4
  5,3,1.6,0.2
  4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3
  6.5,3,5.8,2.2
  5.5,2.5,4,1.3
  6.5,3,5.5,1.8
  5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2
  6.8,3,5.5,2.1
  5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3
  6.7,3.1,4.7,1.5
  5.9,3,4.2,1.5
  5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3
  7.7,3,6.1,2.3
  5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4
  4.6,3.6,1,0.2
  4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2
  6.7,3,5,1.7
  5.6,3,4.5,1.5
  4.3,3,1.1,0.1
  7.1,3,5.9,2.1
  5.8,2.7,4.1,1
  4.9,3.1,1.5,0.2
  5.1,2.5,3,1.1
```

Code -

```
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
 iris = pd.read_csv('test_iris.csv')
 dataset = iris.values
 iris_X = dataset[:,0:4]
 iris_y = [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.,
   0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris_X, iris_y, 
                                    test_size =0.20,random_state=100)
 model = LogisticRegression()
 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
 list_ans= y_pred
 print(list_ans)
 print(len(list_ans))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the test set: it doesn't have any labels. This is what you'd use to test your model after you train it on the training set. Do you have a train_iris.csv file somewhere?

If not, you can import the training data (150 rows) using

```
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X_train = iris.data
y_train = iris.target
```

Comment: I understand this now. Yes, I already had the iris data imported. After you pointed out, have used the test_iris.csv as test set. It worked great. Thanks @Andrew-Mackenzie.